# DC and local user logon failure in windows server 2008R2 enterprise edition

Tags: login

I am currently acting  as the System Administrator,  have problem with logging on to  DC both domain account and Local user (admin) account. Here is the nature of my network, I have got 4 branches that are running additional DCs and they replicate to DC at head quarters (HQ) all running windows server 2008R2.

when I disconnected the DC from the network, feedback is; There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.

when I connected the DC to the network feedback is; You account has been disabled. please see your system administrator.

My failure to logon to the DC at HQ has limited my remote logon onto those other 4 servers (ADC) and even other servers on the network. please help, how can I logon solve this problem?

Comment: Can you not logon to the DC and re-enable the domain admin account via ADUC?

Comment: I can not logon at all even via ADUC, I thought may be there could be away I can reset the password but again the account is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

> problem with logging on to DC both domain account and Local user (admin) account.

Windows Domain Controllers don't have local accounts, so you'll never manage to log in with one. :)

> when I connected the DC to the network feedback is; You account has been disabled. please see your system administrator.

You'll need to log in as a (different) domain Administrator account and unlock your locked domain account.

Answer (score 0):

the first error (when unplugged) somehow seems to indicate that your DC is not set up to resolve names properly (it cannot find a domain controller, probably because the DNS client settings are pointing to another server).

If your account is disabled, then you need to get another domain admin to enable it again and potentially allow for the DCs to replicate (or do it through AD sites and services).

If your domain controller is really fubar and completely out of sync, you could try (very last resort) booting into DS restore mode (with the password you set up when you installed active directory). Evicting it from the domain. Removing the DC from active directory (in another server), allowing to replicate, then re-joining. I would not really recommend this option unless you REALLY know what you are doing.

Another thing you might need to look into is who your FSMO are. If you are unplugging your PDC then your other DCs may throw a bit of a fit.

Comment: I am posting here as I cannot comment on the original question. If you can reset the password, then surely you must be able to enable the account again. Can you not try that?